# Solution of the differential equation $\frac{d^3y}{dx^2}-8\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ satisfying...

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Problem :

Solution of the differential equation $$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}-8\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$$ satisfying $y(0)=\frac{1}{8}, y'(0)=0$ and $y''(0)=1$ is $$ y =\frac{e^{8x}-8x+7}{\lambda}$$ Find the value of $\lambda$

My approach :

$$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}-8\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d^3y}{dx^3} = 8\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

Integrating both sides we get :

$$\Rightarrow  \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =8\frac{dy}{dx}+c$$

Please suggest whether it is the right way of doing this. Please guide further will be of great help. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$?

Comment: Mis-matched indices, not a good sign.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the general solution, so $y(0)=\frac{1+7}{\lambda}=\frac{1}{8}$, so $\lambda=64$. And $y'(0)=\frac{8e^{8*0}-8}{\lambda}=0$, this is true for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Finally $y''(0)=\frac{64e^{8*0}}{\lambda}=1$, in this case $\lambda=64$ is also the only solution. There is precisely one value for $\lambda$, namely $64$.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y''=t\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \frac{d^3y}{dx^3}=t'
$$
(I suppose that you have a typo in the OP and your $\frac{d^3y}{dx^2}$ is for $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$ ) so the equation becoms $t'=8t$ with solution $t=e^{8x}+c_1$.

Now solve:

$$
y''=e^{8x}+c_1
$$
and find: 
$$y'=\frac{1}{8}e^{8x}+c_1x+c_2 $$
$$y=\frac{1}{64}e^{8x}+\frac{c_1}{2}x^2+c_2x+c_3 $$

From the initial conditions we can easily found that:
$$
c_3=\frac{7}{64} \qquad c_2=-\frac{1}{8} \qquad c_1=0
$$

so the solution is:
$$
y=\frac{1}{64} e^{8x} -\frac{1}{8}x+\frac{7}{64}= \dfrac{e^{8x}-8x+7}{64}
$$

and $\lambda=64$.